# Flatten an Observable

Tags: angular, rxjs5, ngrx

I'm trying to get the specific ***Item***, for example, `{ key: "321" }`, from `ngrx/store` based on route parameter. I got it working like this:

```
this.route.params
  .map((params: any) => params.key)

  .mergeMap((key: string) => {

    return this.store.select(state => state.items)

      .mergeMap((items: Observable<any[]>) => items)

      // .do(item => console.log(item, key))

      .filter((item: any) => item.key === key);
  })
  .take(1)
  .subscribe(console.log);
```

where `state.items` is an array of objects, like: `[ {key: "1"}, {key: "2"}, ...]` that fills over time.

I'm wondering is there a better/different way to do this?

Also, why do I get same item multiple (`state.items.length`) times before `.take(1)`?

Comment: Do you want to fetch multiple items from the item array in your store? If that's the case, your code can be optimised.

Comment: @KwintenP I need to get item from the list by value of specific property. For url `/items/123` value is **123** and property is **key**, for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code is pretty good already but the inner mergeMap isn't necessary. The filter should actually be a map if I understand correctly. You are getting an array of items in the store.select statement and in your filter you are handling one item at a time. This shouldn't work since it's the array you're working on. Using a map we can get the item array as input and return the item that is actually the one we are looking for.

```
this.route.params
  .map((params: any) => params.key)
  .mergeMap((key: string) => {
      return this.store.select(state => state.items)

         // no need for this mergeMap
         //.mergeMap((items: Observable<any[]>) => items)

         // map will actually get an array of items as input here
         // we want to get the element from the array matching 
         // the key from the route param and return the first element
         // => [0] since there should be only one
         .map((item: any[]) => items.filter((item) => item.key === key)[0];
})
.take(1)
.subscribe(console.log);
```

Jsbin with mocked working example: http://jsbin.com/sihina/7/edit?js,console

Comment: Yea, functionality is the same, but your way might be more efficient, since `mergeMap()` transforms observable array into array of observables while map+filter work on *pure array*...

Comment: MergeMap doesn't really do what you describe, unless I'm mistaken. MergeMap will perform a function on every element in the observable. The result of this function should be an observable which is flattened by the mergeMap operator.